# Авторизация в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Пробую авторизоваться в `Firebase`, чтобы добавить записи в БД, но выпадает ошибка. Что не так?

**FirebaseActivity.java**

```
public class FirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter;
    private Query query;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    private String userName;
    private String userPhotoUrl;

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        autorization();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("records");
        query = databaseReference.orderByChild("record");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(this, query);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);

        firebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(firebaseAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (firebaseAdapter != null) {
            firebaseAdapter.cleanup();
            firebaseAdapter = null;
        }
    }

    public void writeRecord(long count) {
        Record record = new Record(userName, count, userPhotoUrl);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("records");
        databaseReference.push().setValue(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void autorization() {

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();//здесь ошибка

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser == null) {
            Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            userName = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (userPhotoUrl != null)
                userPhotoUrl = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nikolai.game5nashki, PID: 18959
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Looper;ILcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzk; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk' appears in /data/data/com.example.nikolai.game5nashki/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-10.0.1_7a98136ca02fb177abda2850dae53db6a0e746ca-classes.dex)
                      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$4.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzuQ(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.nikolai.game5nashki.FirebaseActivity.autorization(FirebaseActivity.java:93)
                      at com.example.nikolai.game5nashki.FirebaseActivity.onCreate(FirebaseActivity.java:45)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Что-то не так с либами гугла в папке с СДК. ПОпробуйте перекачать либы в SDK Manager

Comment: Попробуйте в градле добавить вот это:  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1' и нажмите sync затем rebuild

Comment: А права на ветку записи в самой Firebase не забыли прописать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Перекачал либы, к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: @ivansoft Все добавлено изначально, но не помогло, пробовал даже версии менять, не помогает.

Comment: @IvanVovk Немного не понял Ваш вопрос. Не могли бы по подробнее написать, что именно Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @IvanVovk Уже разобрался в данном вопросе сам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. Уже разобрался в данном вопросе сам. Проблема была в несовместимости версий библиотек `FirebaseUI` и `Firebase/Play Services`. Вот здесь описано какие версии совместимы https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android .
Также `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` писать обязательно в конце `gradle` файла.